# HOw do I use PHP to echo wordpress featured images on a seperate page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site which uses PHP to echo results within a MySql database. The results are $link, $description and $title. Here is the code:

```
echo "
<h2><a href='$link'><b>$title</b><img src=\"IMAGE LINK GOES HERE OR PHP\" /></a>    </h2><br>
$description<br />
<a href='$link'>$link<br /><br /></a><p></div></li></ul></div>
";
```

I would like to know how I would echo "Wordpress featured images" from a separate site.

For example:

```
echo <img src="PHP CODE TO GRAB THE IMAGES FROM A WORDPRESS SITE WHICH I HAVE ALREADY CREATED" />
```

Im sorry if Im not making perfect sense. I am rubbish with PHP. Please help....

Comment: you want to use the_post_thumbnail() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

Comment: How do I tell PHP where to look because the images are in a separate directory?

Comment: how do you mean? are the images uploaded to a post?

Comment: I have a file called mysite.com/test.php where all the results of my database are echoed to. I have a wordpress website which is at mywordpresssite.com/ and I want to echo the Posts featured images onto my test.php page....

Comment: Here is the page: http://www.door9.co.uk/s3/search.php?search=a+e&submit=Search+source+code MY GOAL IS TO change the yellow image to unique post images from my wordpress site